# How to fetch unique records from excel in given column using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I can read the data of one col 0 by using below code. I need to fetch unique records from col0.

For example column contains:

1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9

The result should be:

2,3,5,7,8

CODE:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(theNewestFile);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row;
    String cellValueMaybeNull;
    List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

    Map<String, List<String>> duplicateCheck = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    //List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> duplicateValue1 = null;

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= spreadsheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
        row = (XSSFRow) spreadsheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if (row != null) {
            int colIndex = 0;
            Cell cell = row.getCell(colIndex);
            if (cell != null) {
                // Found column and there is value in the cell.
                final int type1 = cell.getCellType();
                if (type1 == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                    cellValueMaybeNull = cell.getStringCellValue();
                else {
                    cellValueMaybeNull = cell.toString();
                    cellValueMaybeNull = String.valueOf(cellValueMaybeNull).split("\\.")[0];
                }

                // Do something with the cellValueMaybeNull here ...
                if (duplicateCheck.get(cellValueMaybeNull) == null) {
                    //duplicateCheck.get(cellValueMaybeNull).add(cellValueMaybeNull);
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>());
                    list.add(cellValueMaybeNull);
                    duplicateCheck.put(cellValueMaybeNull, list);
                    duplicateValue1 = list;
                    System.out.println(duplicateValue1);
                } else {
                    duplicateCheck.get(cellValueMaybeNull).add(cellValueMaybeNull);
                    System.out.println("Duplicatevalue found and hence ignored");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is not returning the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Collection.frequency() to return only items in your list that have occurred once in the list.

```
List<String> listAll = Arrays.asList("1","1","2","3","4","4","4","5","6","6","7","8","9","9");

for (String item : listAll) {
    if (Collections.frequency(listAll, item) == 1) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

The above code prints out 2, 3, 5, 7, 8 as you require.

Answer (score 0):

Another way by using stream and lambda is shown as follows:

```
List<String> listAll = Arrays.asList("1","1","2","3","4","4","4","5","6","6","7","8","9","9");

listAll.stream()
.filter(t -> Collections.frequency(listAll, item) == 1)
.forEach(t -> System.out.print(t));
```